# HandleScope Woes in v8 using low-level audio callback that needs to return values to a js function

Tags: c++, node.js, audio, v8, node.js-addon

Forgive me for a wall of text, but this is a rather specific use-case that is giving me trouble. I reviewed v8 docs, created a handful of tests to ensure things are working correctly, but issues pop up when assembling.

I'm working on an audio system for Node.js, currently testing with portAudio. Defining the callback & getting audio out from Node is not a problem. The issue arises when I need to:

- bring audio vector data into node;
- call a user-defined js function that will forward the audio data from the portAudio callback into Node.

---

I create a new Isolate during initialization to be used by the audio callback (that will be used in an audio callback on a high-priority audio thread):

```
Isolate::CreateParams cp;
cp.array_buffer_allocator = new AudiioArrayBufferAllocator();
auto callbackIsolate = Isolate::New( cp );
std::cout << "storing function ...\n";
callback.Reset( callbackIsolate, Local< Function >::Cast( args[ 5 ] ) );
```

where `callback` is

```
Persistent< Function > callback; 
// js function to hand the audio input to
```

---

We can test this callback from within the initialization function as follows:

```
/// test the callback:
// if below seems odd, see // https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-v0-12-c-apis-breaking/
auto callbackHandle = Local< Function >::New( isolate, callback ); 
// define function arguments & call the function:
Local< Value > arguments[] = { Number::New( isolate, 3.14159 ) };
callbackHandle->Call( Null( isolate ), 1, arguments );
```

Calling the function from Node results in:

```
a = require('./build/Release/audiio');
{ audioDeviceInfo: [Function: audioDeviceInfo],
  initialize: [Function: initialize],
  wrapup: [Function: wrapup],
  updateBuffer: [Function: updateBuffer] }
> a.initialize(2, 2, 44100, 1024, '', function(v){ console.log(v); });
storing function ...
2016-09-19 12:40:08.325 node[39985:4071059] 12:40:08.325 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
3.14159
```

(The bit of text is due to portAudio and it doesn't matter, but useful to see that PortAudio gears are churning...)

---

In the PortAudio Callback, we need to call the JS function that will (eventually) receive the array of sample values from the input. I'm including the full code here. Note that `userData` passed to the audio callback is given the `callbackIsolate` I have defined during the initialization.

```
static int nodeAudioCallback( const    void* input,
                                       void* output,
                              unsigned long numFrames,
                              const    PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* /* timeInfo */,
                                       PaStreamCallbackFlags /* staticFlags */,
                                       void* userData )
{
    auto isolate = static_cast< Isolate* >( userData );
    std::cout << "static_cast< Isolate* > ok.\n";
    Isolate::Scope isolateScope( isolate );
    std::cout << "Isolate::Scope ok\n";
    std::cout << "isolate is " << ( ( isolate == nullptr ) ? "" : "NOT" ) << " nullptr\n";

    Locker lock( isolate );
    HandleScope scope( isolate );
    std::cout << "Locker lock( isolate ) ok.\n";

    // 2. forward the input buffer into the Node callback:
    Local< Value > result[] = { Number::New( isolate, 3.14159 ) };

    std::cout << "Generating a local callbackHandle ... \n";
    auto callbackHandle = Local< Function >::New( isolate, callback );
    std::cout << "Attempting to call the local callbackHandle... \n";
    auto returned = callbackHandle->Call( Null( isolate ), 1, result );
}
```

I'm certain that I'm the one being the idiot here, but the error message is somewhat mystifying and I'm not sure how to fix:

```
> a = require('./build/Release/audiio');
{ audioDeviceInfo: [Function: audioDeviceInfo],
  initialize: [Function: initialize],
  wrapup: [Function: wrapup],
  updateBuffer: [Function: updateBuffer] }
> a.initialize(2, 2, 44100, 1024, '', function(v){ console.log(v); });
storing function ...
2016-09-19 12:56:31.341 node[40063:4089863] 12:56:31.341 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
3.14159
undefined
> static_cast< Isolate* > ok.
Isolate::Scope ok
isolate is NOT nullptr
Locker lock( isolate ) ok.
Generating a local callbackHandle ... 
Attempting to call the local callbackHandle... 

#
# Fatal error in v8::HandleScope::CreateHandle()
# Cannot create a handle without a HandleScope
#

Illegal instruction: 4
```

It seems to me that the HandleScope that the error message refers to must be different from one I defined in the callback function above.

Tried to:

1. Enter the callbackIsolate in initialization & define a HandleScope prior to calling `callback.Reset` (no change)
2. Tried changing the function call to a `MaybeValue` returning call that takes a context, which resulted in `Bus Error: 10`, which means I'm *really* messing things up with memory access.

Since I'm asking for help with a rather particular thing, full code that I have can be seen in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/ilzxc/7ebda4f61e844804459d1fc3fa72f1e4 -- but I'm also rather self-conscious asking others to look at a bunch of code.

Any advice would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: A stack trace could potentially be useful.

Comment: Maybe you need a context scope, since running a function requires a context?  I'm pretty lazy about scopes.. I just make all of them all the time, so I don't really know what is required where.

Comment: also looking at your full code, i don't see where the context for the isolate you create is created or where the callback function is bound to whatever context that is.   I don't know anything about node, but that's how V8 works.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I've isolated the problem in a simpler example and have verified that the function callback defined in one Isolate absolutely can not be called or accessed from another Isolate... Seems that I have a bit more homework to do with inter-thread communication in V8 / Node, so I'm going to go build a few toy examples & will update the question / answer when I have more to say. But, importantly, thanks.

Comment: A function from one context cannot be run in another context, much less another isolate.  Other things can be shared across contexts, but nothing can be shared across isolates.